# How to retrieve JSON payload inside Http interceptor?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to intercept a particular request inside my interceptor. I want to catch 401 http status, which is easy to do with

```
response.code()
```

However I also need to check a particular field in the payload and I cannot find how to retrieve this payload.

Here is my interceptor:

```
Interceptor authorizationInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        if (response.code() == 401) {
            // I need to access the payload here
            return response;
        }

        return response;
   }
};
```

The debugger reveals that the payload is available inside the response.
[image]

Is it possible to retrieve it ?

Comment: what about `response.body().string()` ? remeber that it will consume the response's body

Comment: @Selvin it is exaclty what I needed thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Selvin, the body can be retrieved (as a String) using

```
response.body().string()
```